# hostapd.conf error on hw_mode=g

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, hotspot, docker

I'm trying to create a wireless hotspot with the Raspberry Pi in a dockerized environment.

When I run

```
sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
'ine 3: unknown hw_mode '
```

Config file:

```
interface=wlan0
ssid=Test
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=12345678
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
```

My config file seems to be right. There are no extra white spaces or things like that. I got the hotspot working earlier without Docker (directly on the OS).

I'm running the Docker instance with following command:

```
docker run -it --net=host [censored]/poc-communicatie_hub
```

My docker file is as following:

```
FROM hypriot/rpi-java:1.8.0
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y net-tools
RUN apt-get install hostapd
ADD /vendor/hostapd.conf /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

When I run `ifconfig -a` in my container, I see the wlan0, so I do seem to have access to it.

Comment: I have an update on this. I just ran `cat -v hostapd.conf` and got the following output: `interface=wlan0^M
ssid=Test^M
hw_mode=g^M
channel=6^M
macaddr_acl=0^M
auth_algs=1^M
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0^M
wpa=2^M
wpa_passphrase=12345678^M` It seems like the Windows is adding some control characters to the file when transfering.. Any idea on how I can avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the problem was caused by creating the file in Windows. Doing this added ^M to the end of each line. (You can check if this is the case by executing the command `cat -v hostapd.conf`. I fixed this by creating the same file on Linux and using this one for adding into the Docker image.